# how to open python webservice in browser

Tags: python, web-services

I have a code for simple HelloWorld webservice in python 3 :

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response

@Request.application
def application():
    return Response('Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 4000, application)
```

I want to test this in a browser... I tried to open url : "http://localhost:4000/application" but it is giving an error "500".
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved. Change

`def application():` to `def application(request):`